# How do I move a file into a folder in the iOS version of DropBox?

Tags: ios, dropbox

I uploaded a file from my email to DropBox on my iPad. Then I got several more files of the same type and realized that it would be appropriate to keep all of them in a folder.  I created the folder and was able to put the new files into it, but I see no option to move existing files into existing folders.

- Hold-and-drag doesn't seem to work.
- The 'edit' menu doesn't seem to work.

**Is it possible to move an existing file into an existing folder in DropBox on the iPad? And if so, how?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steve

There is no method on either iPad or iPhone to move an item between folders.

Comment: Darn.  That's unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is just a shortcoming of the app. I usually just go online to complete this.